# Drupal 7, block on all profile pages. Printing fields from 'viewed user' not 'current user'

Tags: drupal-7, profile

I'm trying to print a few fields in a block on each profile page.

The block needs to display the fields of the user being viewed, not the logged in user.

$account = user_load($node->uid); - doesn't work. user->uid doesn't either.
Globals user will return the logged in users info.

Not exactly sure how I'm supposed to load anything into a block. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're viewing a user profile with a URL path like this

`drupal/user/USER_ID`

You can do as follows :

```php
// Option 1
$user = explode('/', current_path());
$user_id = end($user);

// Option 2
// $path = explode('/', current_path());
// $user_id = $path[count($path)-1];
$account = user_load($user_id, true);
```

Documentation [current_path()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/current_path/7)

This way you get the last part of the URL and pass it to the `user_load` function. We set `true` as second parameter so it loads from the DB and not the cache.

Another way to do the same without breaking the URL into pieces is to use [arg()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7) to get the parameters

In this case the code would look like this

```php
// Option 3
// drupal/user/USER_ID
// drupal = arg(0)
// user = arg(1)
// USER_ID = arg(2)
$account = user_load(arg(2), true);
```

In both cases check that `$user_id` is an integer, do not let it pass at least is an integer, then you can check the result of `user_load`.

**Update**

If you are using the user's name in the URL you can load a full `user` object by using [user_load_by_name()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_load_by_name/7)

So the code would change a little bit. Try this :

```php
$account = user_load_by_name(arg(2));
```

I used `arg` for simplicity, you can get the user's name from URL as you want.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for that!

I'm using a custom path for the url [user:roles]/[user:name-raw]
so to give i.e. example.com/writers/username or example.com/editors/username

I've tried searching for a way to get the info by URL but I'm coming up empty.

Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for the update!

I got it to work with the following:
$user_id = end(explode('/', current_path()));
$account = user_load($user_id, true);

I'm assuming it getting the user ID from the url before clean-url's kicks in. Devel is showing that it's the user ID number being pulled too.

I'm now getting this error, it's working though.
Only variables should be passed by reference in eval() (line 2 of /home/myliving/public_html/modules/php/php.module(80) : eval()'d code).

That would be this: $user_id = end(explode('/', current_path()));

Comment: I updated my answer. Check the first example, I fixed it. I shouldn't have passed the `explode` function directly but a variable. Now it shouldnt show that error message.